# Include pods in main target and not in WatchKit extension

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I added a WatchKit extension to my current project. The project uses Cocoapods **0.36.1** to add some frameworks, but now I want to exclude some pods from the WatchKit extension project.

The WatchKit extension project doesn't need a lot of frameworks I use in my normal target, but I can't get Cocoapods to work correct after altering my Podfile.

I use `use_frameworks!` in my Podfile, but after running `pod install` I get the following messages:

```
[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `HomeHandler` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-HomeHandler/Pods-HomeHandler.debug.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-HomeHandler/Pods-HomeHandler.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration.
[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `HomeHandler` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-HomeHandler/Pods-HomeHandler.release.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-HomeHandler/Pods-HomeHandler.release.xcconfig` in your build configuration.
[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `HomeHandler WatchKit Extension` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-HomeHandler WatchKit Extension/Pods-HomeHandler WatchKit Extension.debug.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-HomeHandler WatchKit Extension/Pods-HomeHandler WatchKit Extension.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration.
[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `HomeHandler WatchKit Extension` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-HomeHandler WatchKit Extension/Pods-HomeHandler WatchKit Extension.release.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-HomeHandler WatchKit Extension/Pods-HomeHandler WatchKit Extension.release.xcconfig` in your build configuration.
```

I didn't change any settings for my the base configurations, but 2 of my 3 targets have the right `Pods.debug` or `Pods.release` set. The one without base configuration is the WatchKit **App**.

**My original Podfile**

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 2.0.0'
pod 'MagicalRecord', :git => "https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord.git"
pod 'PureLayout'
pod 'UAProgressView'
pod 'UICKeyChainStore'
pod 'XLForm', git: 'git@github.com:xmartlabs/XLForm.git'
pod 'Classy', git: 'git@github.com:depl0y/Classy.git'
pod 'Reveal-iOS-SDK', :configurations => ['Debug']
pod 'JBChartView', '~> 2.8.9'
pod 'RFQuiltLayout'
pod 'HUMSlider', '~> 1.0'
pod 'SwiftEventBus', :git => 'https://github.com/cesarferreira/SwiftEventBus.git'

post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == "Pods-AFNetworking"
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] = ['$(inherited)', 'AF_APP_EXTENSIONS=1']
            end
        end
        if target.name == "Pods-PureLayout"
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] = ['$(inherited)', 'PURELAYOUT_APP_EXTENSIONS=1']
            end
        end
    end
end
```

**My altered Podfile**

This is where I want to exclude certain pods from my WatchKit project.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

link_with "HomeHandler", "HomeHandler WatchKit Extension"

pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 2.0.0'
pod 'MagicalRecord', :git => "https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord.git"

pod 'UICKeyChainStore'

target :HomeHandler do
    pod 'XLForm', git: 'git@github.com:xmartlabs/XLForm.git'
    pod 'UAProgressView'
    pod 'Classy', git: 'git@github.com:depl0y/Classy.git'
    pod 'Reveal-iOS-SDK', :configurations => ['Debug']
    pod 'JBChartView', '~> 2.8.9'
    pod 'RFQuiltLayout'
    pod 'HUMSlider', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'SwiftEventBus', :git => 'https://github.com/depl0y/SwiftEventBus.git'
    pod 'PureLayout'
end

post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == "Pods-AFNetworking"
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] = ['$(inherited)', 'AF_APP_EXTENSIONS=1']
            end
        end
        if target.name == "Pods-PureLayout"
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] = ['$(inherited)', 'PURELAYOUT_APP_EXTENSIONS=1']
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The warnings outputted by CocoaPods is due to two CocoaPods targets are trying to be linked to a single target in your application (which isn't supported).

I.e, you have an explicit target `HomeHandler` *and* you are linking the nameless target to HomeHandler too with `link_with "HomeHandler", "HomeHandler WatchKit Extension"`.

My suggestion would be to revamp your Podfile to look something like the following:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

def shared_pods
    pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git'
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 2.0.0'
    pod 'MagicalRecord', :git => "https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord.git"
    pod 'UICKeyChainStore'
end

target 'HomeHandler' do
    shared_pods
    pod 'XLForm', git: 'git@github.com:xmartlabs/XLForm.git'
    pod 'UAProgressView'
    pod 'Classy', git: 'git@github.com:depl0y/Classy.git'
    pod 'Reveal-iOS-SDK', :configurations => ['Debug']
    pod 'JBChartView', '~> 2.8.9'
    pod 'RFQuiltLayout'
    pod 'HUMSlider', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'SwiftEventBus', :git => 'https://github.com/depl0y/SwiftEventBus.git'
    pod 'PureLayout'
end

target 'HomeHandler WatchKit Extension' do
    shared_pods
end
```

Comment: i am getting this error: library not found for -lPods-Project_name WatchKit Extension . MY pod file is :
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project # platform :ios, '8.0' # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift # use_frameworks! platform :ios, :deployment_target => “7.0” target 'Project_name' , :exclusive => true do pod 'Google/Analytics' end target 'Project_name WatchKit Extension' do pod 'Google/Analytics' end target 'Project_name WatchKit App' do pod 'Google/Analytics' end @kylef

Comment: this is not working for me under xcode 8. It installs well without problem but when I compile the project there are thousands of errors related to pods being included on the app extension even when they are not included on the `target do end` block of the extension.