# Archive build with split pods across app and watchkit extension

Tags: ios, xcode6, cocoapods, watchkit

I have been unable to get Cocoapods to build a deployable iOS app that requires different pods for the app and the watchkit extension.  I have tried a format suggested in another thread: [Include pods in main target and not in WatchKit extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321844/include-pods-in-main-target-and-not-in-watchkit-extension)

but it has numerous failures, including not finding headers.  Here's the closest I can get:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

link_with 'RailTime-WatchKit-Extension'

pod 'Reachability'
pod 'IGInterfaceDataTable'

target :'RailTime', :exclusive=>true do
    pod 'ASIHTTPRequest', '~> 1.8.2'
    pod 'BPXLUUIDHandler', '~> 0.0.1'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9'
    pod 'Appirater', '~> 2.0.4'
end
```

This works fine for the simulator, but fails when trying to install on a device.  The first error is:

ld: library not found for -lPods-RailTime-WatchKit-Extension

I'm using the latest Cocoapods right now .37.  No errors are generated when performing a pod install.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Ken

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general format that I use for my WatchKit app. See if this helps:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'RailTime-WatchKit-Extension' do

link_with 'RailTime-WatchKit-Extension'

pod 'Reachability'
pod 'IGInterfaceDataTable'

end

target :'RailTime' do

link_with 'RailTime'

pod 'ASIHTTPRequest', '~> 1.8.2'
pod 'BPXLUUIDHandler', '~> 0.0.1'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9'
pod 'Appirater', '~> 2.0.4'

end
```

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I saw another suggestion that I restart with a 'pod init', and then fill everything in.  I did that, and it worked!  Although I have no idea why.  Here's what I have now that has successfully deployed my app:  platform :ios, '8.2'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'RailTime' do
 pod 'Reachability'
 pod 'ASIHTTPRequest', '~> 1.8.2'
 pod 'BPXLUUIDHandler', '~> 0.0.1'
 pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9'
 pod 'Appirater', '~> 2.0.4'
end

target 'RailTime-WatchKit-Extension' do
 pod 'Reachability'
 pod 'IGInterfaceDataTable'
end

target 'RailTime-WatchKit-App' do

end

Answer (score 0):

OK, the solution was quite simple, even though I'm not sure why it worked.  As suggested in another thread, I did a 'pod init', which now creates a template that is knowledgable about the multiple targets.  I then just filled it in!  Here's what I have now:

```
platform :ios, '8.2'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'RailTime' do
    pod 'Reachability'
    pod 'ASIHTTPRequest', '~> 1.8.2'
    pod 'BPXLUUIDHandler', '~> 0.0.1'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9'
    pod 'Appirater', '~> 2.0.4'
end

target 'RailTime-WatchKit-Extension' do
    pod 'Reachability'
    pod 'IGInterfaceDataTable'
end

target 'RailTime-WatchKit-App' do

end
```